# apply s3 lifecycle policy on existing objects

Tags: python, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I am applying s3 lifecycle policy on existing bucket. I applied tags to specific objects which I want to apply lifecycle. But I am having an issue here as the objects are already created with different creation date. I am not able to decide how to apply transition and expiration date.
Some objects are old as 3 years while some are old as 1 year.

Any help would be appreciated.